# Not able to Fetch email in otrs

Tags: centos, imap, perl, otrs

I am trying to setup a otrs ticketing tool , the tool needs to fetch email and generate ticket, when I am setting that with my google mail account its working however when I am using my professional mail it is not. its still fetching the email but the tickets are not getting generated, any help on this.

the log says

> CommunicationLog(ID:35,AccountType:-,AccountID:-,Direction:Incoming,Transport:Email,ObjectLogType:Connection,ObjectLogID:41)::Kernel::System::MailAccount::IMAPS => IMAPS: Failed to process message (saved as /opt/otrs/var/spool/problem-email-708adea1ff55d4913fe9768604173beb).

the emails are getting fetched and landing on folder `/opt/otrs/var/spool/`